# Sieve add message to body

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I want to add a Sieve filter rule that add message to body.

It worked to add a message to the subject.

```
if allof(not address :domain :is ["from"] ["example.com""], not header :contains "Subject" ["[TEXT]"])
{
    if header :matches "Subject" "*"
    {
        set "subject" "${1}";
        deleteheader "Subject";
        addheader :last "Subject" "[TEXT]  ${1}";
    }
}
```

I cannot find out how to add a message to the body.
Can anyone help me? Please.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to write your own filter program using dovecot sieve `extprograms` plugin.  Email MIME structure is complicated, there is even messages without text body.  Would you provide more specific details that you're trying to achieve?  Isn't that enough to add custom email headers?